C++17 std::visit perfomance vs dynamic inheritance
Using std::visit in parallel with std::variant, does it give a better performance in comparison with dynamic inheritance using virtual?
Based on cppreference there is the following statement

On typical implementations, the time complexity of the invocation of
vis can be considered equal to that of access to an element in an
(possibly multidimensional) array or execution of a switch statement.

Does it depend on the number of types are kept in the variant?

They are both constant time in the number of types if implemented well.

"does it give a better performance" - I would guess it depends on what optimizations the compiler is able to see possible. "Does it depend on the number of types are kept in variant?" - Yes, the switch-like construct in the implementations I've looked look very different depending on how many types there are.

@TedLyngmo I haven't looked at the implementations, but if they are implemented well, then they should fall back to an indirect call through an array of function pointers once the numbers of types becomes large, in order to achieve constant time complexity. Of course, the compiler can also potentially perform that transformation.

@user17732522 I actually don't remember exactly how it looked, just that there was some threshold where they changed approach. An array of function pointers may be possible with some intrinsic compiler extension, but I don't remember seeing that. Then again, I only remember that it was a lot different depending on the amount :-)

https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/kst2pu/with_stdvariant_you_choose_either_performance_or/?rdt=64175  Unfortunately in its current implementation it is not an alternative to inheritance.

I dont know how it is with std::visit, though the "slowness" of inheritance and virtual methods is mainly from not being able to inline function calls. The relative cost of that is more the less the functions are actually doing, ie usually the cost can be neglected (but not always)

@user17732522 I took a peek at gcc's visit and it says "Creates a multi-dimensional vtable recursively" / "The returned multi-dimensional vtable can be fast accessed by the visitor using index calculation", so pretty much what you said I guess, but the code in there is tricky to read :-) constexpr size_t __max = 11; // "These go to eleven." seems to be some kind of limit for the switch case.
